# posting data over network doesn't work in java.io API

Tags: java, jersey, java-io

I have the below piece of code that works fine when run from eclipse

```
 String str = "testing";
 InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
 int length = is.available();
 byte[] data = new byte[length];
 is.read(data, 0, length);
 System.out.println("output "+new String(data));
```

When I break this code to post the data over network using Jerser client API and try read it back on the server using Jersey I don't get the value that I posted. The client code looks like this

```
public static void main(String s[]) throws IOException {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    String str = "testingthi";
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
    WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://192.168.1.15:8090/JersySample/resources/stream/upload");

    ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).post(ClientResponse.class,is);
    is.close();
}
```

The code on the server looks like this

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
 public Response upload( InputStream is) {
    try{
        int size = is.available();
        byte data[] = new byte[size];
        is.read(data,0,size);           
        System.out.println(" Posted data is "+ new String(data)+" length is "+size+"  stream size "+is.available());
        is.close();
   }catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
    return Response.ok().entity("Done").build();
}
```

When I read the string using apache-commons-io API I do get the string value that I posted. Can someone explain why it doesn't work using the java.io API which was working in non-network situation?

Comment: You aren't 'posting an InputStream over the network'. You can't. You are posting *data* over the network.

Answer (score 1):

You're making the usual mistake of assuming that read() fills the buffer. It isn't obliged to do that. See the Javadoc. It's only obliged to read at least one byte and return. The byte count, return -1, or throw an IOException.

You're also misusing available(). It doesn't return the total number of bytes in the stream, and the way you're using it is specifically warned against in the Javadoc.

Comment: Why does it work when I run it in eclipse but fail when I use the same api methods over network?